# How can I connecti Raspberry pi 4 to pixhawk?

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, telemetry, dronekit-python

I want to create a connection between pixhawk and raspberry pi 4 model B.

When I connect the Pixhawk to the usb port of raspberry via micro-usb, I can send commands to the pixhawk with the drone-kit scripts on raspberry.

[image]

[image]

However, when I connect the telemtry2 port to raspberry's 14th and 15th GPIO pins (rx-tx) in pixhawks, the same script gives a heartbeat error.

[image]

[image]

I have done the configuration of uart pins with rasp-config. The /boot/config.txt file is as follows. Also, when connecting from usb, I use the connection string value "/ dev / ttyACM0" and "/ dev / serial0" when the UART pins are connected.

[image]

Via mission planner:
SERIAL 2 PROTOCOL = 2  , SERIAL2 BAUD = 921

I followed this link: https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink.html

Since there is no GPS installed, I set the GPS and compass control values ​​to 0 on the mission planner. That's why the pixhawk is in arm state. (blue light)

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the following parameters?

`MAV_1_CONFIG = TELEM 2` (MAV_1_CONFIG is often used to map the TELEM 2 port)

`MAV_1_MODE = Onboard`

`SER_TEL2_BAUD = 921600` (921600 or higher recommended for applications like log streaming or FastRTPS)

Reference:
https://docs.px4.io/master/en/companion_computer/pixhawk_companion.html#companion-computer-setup

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because you welded a Dupont cable to JST-GH connector, while it may work it also leaves room to electrical incompatibility and increased signal interferences, best bet is to buy a premade Dupont to JST-GH cable.

Answer (score -2):

there is an easy way to connect raspberry pi with cube autopilot. the companion board lychee
https://dronee.aero/pages/lychee